# How do I get a floating button like uber

Tags: android, floating-action-button, floating

I want to create a floating button like Uber. Uber shows a floating button when online and hides it when offline. Also "DU recorder" app has the floating button.

I want the floating button remain on top of all apps and be movable on any place on screen.

I have Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with Android 8 (Oreo)

Comment: take a look here https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-chat-head/

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code 

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MovableFloatingActionButton extends FloatingActionButton implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final static float CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE = 10; // Often, there will be a slight, unintentional, drag when the user taps the FAB, so we need to account for this.

    private float downRawX, downRawY;
    private float dX, dY;

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){

        int action = motionEvent.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            downRawX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            downRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();
            dX = view.getX() - downRawX;
            dY = view.getY() - downRawY;

            return true; // Consumed

        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            int viewWidth = view.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = view.getHeight();

            View viewParent = (View)view.getParent();
            int parentWidth = viewParent.getWidth();
            int parentHeight = viewParent.getHeight();

            float newX = motionEvent.getRawX() + dX;
            newX = Math.max(0, newX); // Don't allow the FAB past the left hand side of the parent
            newX = Math.min(parentWidth - viewWidth, newX); // Don't allow the FAB past the right hand side of the parent

            float newY = motionEvent.getRawY() + dY;
            newY = Math.max(0, newY); // Don't allow the FAB past the top of the parent
            newY = Math.min(parentHeight - viewHeight, newY); // Don't allow the FAB past the bottom of the parent

            view.animate()
                    .x(newX)
                    .y(newY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();

            return true; // Consumed

        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            float upRawX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            float upRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();

            float upDX = upRawX - downRawX;
            float upDY = upRawY - downRawY;

            if (Math.abs(upDX) < CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(upDY) < CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE) { // A click
                return performClick();
            }
            else { // A drag
                return true; // Consumed
            }

        }
        else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

    }

}

//-------------------this code inside the xml file -----------
<com.example.MovableFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_white_24dp"/>
```

Comment: Though This gives me a floating button it is tied to my MainActivity Layout. I want this to be not tied to my MainActivity layout. I want it always available whether my app is in the foreground or background.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains multiple questions so let us break it down and take it to step by step.

**For Creating Floating Button:**

I would say use @Vishal Sharma answer about this question in this page

**And about showing and hiding it when the user is online or offline:**

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    protected Set<NetworkStateReceiverListener> listeners;
    protected Boolean connected;

    public NetworkStateReceiver() {
        listeners = new HashSet<NetworkStateReceiverListener>();
        connected = null;
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent == null || intent.getExtras() == null)
            return;

        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            connected = true;
        } else if(intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
            connected = false;
        }

        notifyStateToAll();
    }

    private void notifyStateToAll() {
        for(NetworkStateReceiverListener listener : listeners)
            notifyState(listener);
    }

    private void notifyState(NetworkStateReceiverListener listener) {
        if(connected == null || listener == null)
            return;

        if(connected == true)
            listener.networkAvailable();
        else
            listener.networkUnavailable();
    }

    public void addListener(NetworkStateReceiverListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
        notifyState(l);
    }

    public void removeListener(NetworkStateReceiverListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    public interface NetworkStateReceiverListener {
        public void networkAvailable();
        public void networkUnavailable();
    }
}
```

YOUR ACTIVITY:

```
public class MyActivity implements NetworkStateReceiverListener {
    private NetworkStateReceiver networkStateReceiver;
}
```

IN YOUR ACTIVITY: INSTANTIATE THE RECEIVER

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    networkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver();
    networkStateReceiver.addListener(this);
    this.registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    networkStateReceiver.removeListener(this);
    this.unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
}
```

IN YOUR ACTIVITY: IMPLEMENTS THE REQUIRED METHODS

```
@Override
public void networkAvailable() {
    /* TODO: show your button here */
}

@Override
public void networkUnavailable() {
    /* TODO: hide your button here */        
}
```